# I want the flash delay to start for 3 seconds

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs6

Now I am using the Flash CS6 and try to start the flash after I open it 3 seconds. what can I do? I am a beginner, so could you tell me how to do

Comment: Add `frame rate x 3` frames at the beginning of your timeline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout

```
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

setTimeout(initPage, 3000); // Time is in milliseconds so 3000 = 3 seconds

function initPage(){
    // go to some frame or do other stuff if you are not using timeline
}
```